# Vim Equivalent of Spyder's Variable Explorer

Tags: vimrc

I am used to coding python in Spyder IDE and wanted to change to vim. I started using vim not long ago, but I miss the variable explorer implemented in Spyder. For those not familiar with Spyder, the variable explorer is a tool that displays all the variables from the compiled python file. I find this very useful because I don't need to print all the variables I want and can view the arrays completely. Is there any plugin for vim that has a similar tool?

Comment: How about https://andrew.stwrt.ca/posts/vim-ctags/ and https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar ? Otherwise, you should look for a program that generate this information (the variables) and then add this into vim, not the other way around.

Comment: I have to say wow to this question. What I want to ask has been asked 5 years ago.

Comment: @nobe4: No, that's not "Variable Explorer" in Spyder. What (s)he meant is a plugin that can __inspect__ the value of those variables. So it's more like a debugger.